# string JSON without "" on JAXRS response

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I've created an endpoint:

```
@Path(value = "/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface IUserCommtyEndpoint {
    @POST
    public abstract Response create(
        @HeaderParam("user") String username
    );
```

As you can see I've specified that this endpoint produces `MetiaType.APPLICATION_JSON`.

This is the implementation:

```
@Override
public Response create(String username) {
    String userId = "some string";
    return Response
        .created(this.uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(userId).build())
        .entity(userId)
        .build();
}
```

Nevertheless, the response body content is `some string` whithout `""`. So, browser is not able to parse this string value using a json format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/231) you can find an answer.

Shortly, send a single string is not correct.

Comment: According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45274396/91497, the newest JSON RFC 7159, `"some string"` is in fact valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45274396/91497) to the question "Is `""` a valid JSON string?", the newest JSON [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-2) indicates that `"some string"` is in fact valid JSON.

This other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25367452/91497) helped me to find a solution to the problem server side using jackson:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class StringMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<String> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(final Class<?> type, final Type genericType, final Annotation[] annotations, final MediaType mediaType) {
        return type == String.class && MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.equals(mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(final String t, final Class<?> type, final Type genericType, final Annotation[] annotations, final MediaType mediaType, final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, final OutputStream out) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.writeValue(out, t);
    }
}
```